# How to format the string with in the cell of a Excel sheet using perl language

Tags: perl

I am using win32::Ole module,I am trying to format the string as bold with colorindex ,which is in cell of a excel sheet, can you please suggest me which method is used for that..

```
Formatprgm.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE;
my prgm=fn_prgm();
sub fn_prgm
{
  $inputfile="C:\Users\u304079\Desktop\Santu123\CurrentData.xlsx";
  my $Excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');
  my $Workbook = $Excel->Workbooks->Open($inputfile);
  my $sheet = $Workbook->Worksheets(1);
  my $cell1val=$sheet->Cells(1,1)->{value};
   #here i want to format the text in $cell1val

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also use [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel) for this:

```
       use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

       # Create a new Excel workbook
       my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('perl.xls');

       # Add a worksheet
       $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

       #  Add and define a format
       $format = $workbook->add_format(); # Add a format
       $format->set_bold();
       $format->set_color('red');
       $format->set_align('center');

       # Write a formatted and unformatted string, row and column notation.
       $col = $row = 0;
       $worksheet->write($row, $col, 'Hi Excel!', $format);
       $worksheet->write(1,    $col, 'Hi Excel!');
```

**UPD**

In order to rewrite an existing Excel file you should use **Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser**

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    The "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser" module rewrite an existing Excel 
>    file by reading it with "Spreadsheet::ParseExcel"
>    and rewriting it with "Spreadsheet::WriteExcel".
> ```

Comment: It is working but i want to use win32::OLE module,can you please suggest me method for fomatting the text in cell

Comment: WriteExcel module is used for only newly created excel sheets,but i want to format the text in existing excel file,can you please suggest me....